# why does .isnumeric() work inconsistently, only with number 1 | Python 3

Tags: python, isnumeric

Hey I have encounter a problem writing my if-else function using .isnumeric().
in the following I wanted a different outcome depending on if the input is a number in the range of 4 or the letter w while also printing out an error if its none of the above.
So, I first check if its numeric and if it’s in range.

```
user_input = input("type here: ")
if user_input.isnumeric() and int(user_input) == any(range(4)):
    print("do stuff 1")
elif user_input == "example":
    print("do stuff 2")
else:
    print("error")
```

but for some reason it only works with the number 1 for any other number like 0,2,3 it prints the error message.
what am I missing?
why does it only work on number 1.

Comment: `any(range(4))` is `True` and `True` has an integer value of `1`. Maybe you wanted `int(user_input) in range(4)` instead.

Comment: Next step after you fixed that: Check the code with an input value of `²` (hint `'²'.isnumeric()` will give you `True`).

Comment: `isnumeric` is a Unicode character property check, not a check for if a string represents a number. `'-4'` and `'1.0'` both report `False` for `isnumeric`. If you want to check whether a string represents an integer, the way to do that in Python is to try to call `int` on it and see if it works. (Yes, this is using exceptions for control flow. That's normal in Python. Even the basic `for` loop uses exceptions for control flow under the hood.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not coming from `str.isnumeric`, but rather from the other condition you are checking in that same if-statement.
What is happening is a bit complicated though, and to understand it you need to decompose the line :

1. The statement `any(range(4))` evaluates to `True`, as the `range(4)` object contains non-zero integer values which evaluate to `True` (as opposed to a `range(0)` object, which would evaluate to `False` as it is an empty sequence or `range(1)` since it contains only a zero integer value). For more on this, see [Python docs on truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#truth)
2. This `True` value is then being compared to `int(user_input)`. This is an integer comparison, which is comparing the boolean `True` value as if it were an integer value (which, it technically is, since [`bool` is a subclass of `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#boolean-values)). `int(True)` evaluates to `1`, meaning the comparison fails for any user input not equal to `"1"`.
3. Since you're using an `and`, this causes the entire if-statement to fail, dumping you into the else-clause.

I suspect you intended to check if the `user_input` value is between 0 and 4. The correct way to do this would be with the `in` keyword, rather than the `any` function :

```py
if user_input.isnumeric() and int(user_input) in range(4):
    ...
```

Comment: "as opposed to a `range(0)` object, which would evaluate to `False` as it only contains a zero integer value". Actually `bool(range(0))` evaluates to `False` because `range(0)` is an empty sequence, it doen't contain any integers

Comment: `list(range(1))` equals `[0]`, `bool(range(1))` equals `True` and `any(range(1))` equals `False`

Comment: @Hoodlum The length of an iterable is not the main part the `any` function looks at. Your answers previous version was correct except for the "_only contains a zero integer value_" because `range(0)` is actually an empty iterable.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you're right, I should have looked at the documentation of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) directly